# Creating a program to create a simple dart file

Tags: dart

Let's say we want to create a simple dart file, that just declares a class containing consts. E.g.

```
class StringNames {
   static const String helloWorld = 'Hello World';
}
```

But rather than write this manually, we want to generate this file programmatically. We want a program that will create this file for us.

We could write such a program in dart itself, e.g.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final f1 = 'file1.dart';
  File(f1).writeAsString('class stringNames {\nstatic const String helloWorld = \'HelloWorld\';\n}');
}
```

Naturally this feels wrong. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Try the [source_gen package](https://pub.dev/packages/source_gen).

Answer (score 0):

You could use multi-line string as described here in the Dart language tour:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings

So your example becomes like this, which is much more readable:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final f1 = 'file1.dart';
  File(f1).writeAsString('''
class StringNames {
   static const String helloWorld = 'Hello World';
}
''');
}
```

You can also use this and insert values from variables inside the string like this:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final f1 = 'file1.dart';
  final someValue = 42;
  
  File(f1).writeAsString('''
class StringNames {
   static const String helloWorld = 'Hello World';
   static const int someValue = $someValue;
}
''');
}
```